# Get frames from webcam

Tags: matlab, webcam, video-capture

Here is my test code to capture frames from webcam. The feed terminates prematurely. I don't know why. Someone, help. Only two or three frames are captured and then it exits prematurely.

```
vid = videoinput('winvideo', 1);
triggerconfig(vid, 'manual');
set(vid, 'FramesPerTrigger', 1);
set(vid, 'TriggerRepeat', inf);
set(vid, 'ReturnedColorSpace', 'grayscale');

start(vid);

try
     while(vid.FramesAcquired <= 3)
         trigger(vid);

       img = getdata(vid);
       imshow(img);
       hold on; 

       disp('acquired');
    end
catch
    disp('Error');
    stop(vid);
end
disp('exit');
stop(vid);
```

Comment: If you could provide the error message this would be way easier.

Answer (score 1):

check this line of code:

```
while(vid.FramesAcquired <= 3)
```

change the number (3) to the number of the frames you need.